# Trigger tool event on Paper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, paperjs

My app is using Paper.js as a framework for drawing elements, and I am currently coding some tests.

I need to trigger tool events manually, but I'm getting a '**emit is not a function**' error.

I'm doing it like this:

```
tool.emit('mousedown', {
  point:  new Point(5, 5)
});
```

What's wrong with my code? According to [Paper.js documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/#emit-type-event):

> emit(type, event)  Emit an event on the tool.
>
> Parameters: type:
>   String('mousedown'|'mouseup'|'mousedrag'|'mousemove'|'keydown'|'keyup')
>   — the event type event: Object — an object literal containing
>   properties describing the event Returns: Boolean — true if the event
>   had listeners, false otherwise

If I debug my code, tool is a `Tool` object, but `emit` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `emit` is not the correct function to trigger event on `Tool` objects. Paper.js doesn't document `fire` function (at least in newer versions).

My code needs to be like this to work:

```
tool.fire('mousedown', {
  point:  new Point(5, 5)
});
```